# Python Subsequence

Tags: python-2.7

Example: I have the array[9,0,1,2,3,6,4,5,0,9,7,8,9] and It should return the max consecutive subsequence, so the answer should be (and if the number is 9 and the next one is 0 than it's fine) 9,0,1,2,3, but my code is returning 0,1,2,3

Comment: FYI you don't need the condition `or (arr[i] == 0 and arr[j] == 1)` since that's handled by the condition `arr[j] - arr[i] == 1`

Comment: FYI you can use the built-in `max()` function: `maxx = max(l, key=len)`

Comment: Your nested loops are comparing every pair of elements, not just consecutive elements.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I made a few changes and posted again

Comment: Why do you have the condition `or arr[i] > arr[j]`?

Comment: You're still not comparing consecutive elements. The `for j` loop iterates over all the elements before `i`, not just the element just before.

Comment: I truly don't know, lol, I'm a little bit confused, I drawed on the paper but it still doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

Starting from each element, do a loop that compares adjacent elements, until you get a pair that isn't consecutive.

Instead of saving all the consecutive sublists in another list, just save the sublist in a variable. When you get another sublist, check if it's longer and replace it.

```
def constructPrintLIS(arr: list, n: int):
    longest_seq = []
    
    for i in range(n-1):
        for j in range(i, n-1):
            if not (arr[j] == arr[j+1]-1 or (arr[j] == 9 and arr[j+1] == 0)):
                break
        else:
            # if we reach the end, need to update j
            j = n
        if j - i > len(longest_seq):
            longest_seq = arr[i:j+1]

        if n - i <= len(longest_seq): 
            # there can't be any longer sequences, so stop
            break
    
    printLIS(longest_seq)
```

Comment: I don't know if I'm dumb or something, but when I try to test that function the code just breaks and doesn't print anything

Comment: Sorry, I added the last condition after I tested, and I got the condition backwards. It should be `<=`

Comment: Thanks, I tried using your function but it still only returns 0,1,2,3 not 9,0,1,2,3

Comment: Stupid typo, I was comparing both with `0` instead of `9` and `0`.

Comment: Thank u a lot man

Comment: If a had a case that the arr[j] == 9 and the arr[j+1] == 0 is the longest sequence, how could I treat that case?

Comment: The code already works in that case, it will find that sequence.

Comment: I just tested with `arr=[1,1,1,9,0,2,2,2]` and the answer was `[9, 0]`

Comment: I tested with ```arr = [5, 3, 5, 9, 0]  ```  and the answer was nothing

Comment: I have a bug when the longest sub-sequence is at the end of the sequence. I'm working on it.

Comment: Fixed it now. I need to handle the case where the `for j` loop ends at `n-1`, it has to increment `j` to point to `n`.

Comment: Thank u so man, I'm so grateful for your help, you probably saved my life